# Why $\operatorname{dim}X < \infty$ in the proof of the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry. Theorem 14.114?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Theorme 14.114 and some question arises.

: [image]

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? In our situation, is there an irreducible component $X_0$ of $X$ such that

$$\operatorname{dim}(f|_{X_0}^{-1}(\eta)) = \operatorname{dim}(f^{-1}(\eta) \cap X_0) = \operatorname{dim}_{\theta_0}f^{-1}(\eta) < \infty $$

? ($\theta_0$ is the generic point of the $X_0$) If so, how to prove..

Comment: Does "$X$ is equidimensional" entail that all irreducible components are of finite dimension?

Comment: @red_trumpet : Really? I don't know certainly it is yet.~~ Why he wrote $\operatorname{dim}X < \infty$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $X$ equidimensional means that all irreducible components of $X$ have finite dimension $d$ (Görtz is not entirely clear in his definition on page 120, but otherwise the statement $\dim X < \infty$ clearly false). Then any chain of irreducible subsets
$$X_0 \supsetneq X_1 \supsetneq \dots \supsetneq X_k$$
is contained in one irreducible component $X'$ (which contains $X_0$). Hence $k \leq \dim X' =  d$, so $\dim X = d$.

Tbh that proof is quite confusing, because in the equation above he already writes $\dim X' = \dim X$...

Also I think he confused $X$ and $Y$ i the statement of the theorem, it should be
$$\dim Y + \dim f^{-1}(y) = \dim X.$$
This is corrected in the second edition from 2020, see [the errata](https://www.algebraic-geometry.de/errata/1/).

Comment: O.K. somewhat helpful. And it should be $\operatorname{dim}Y + \operatorname{dim}f^{-1}(y) = \operatorname{dim}X$  (I saw it in Gortz's errata) And as "otherwise the statement $\operatorname{dim}X <\infty$ clearly false" , can you explain in more detail what it means exactly? Does it means, possibility of $\operatorname{dim}X = \infty$ in the case that each dimension of irreducible components can be varied(possibly infinite) ?

Comment: (Uhm.. Possibility of the existence of such irreducible component in our qeustion can be false?..)

Comment: @Plantation The irreducible components are the maximal irreducible subsets. So the irreducible set $X_0$ is contained in an irreducible component.

Comment: How about not assuming "$\operatorname{dim}X'=d$" for all irreducible component $X'$ and for some finite $d$ ?  :)

Comment: @Plantation If that is not the case, then $\dim X' = \infty$, and so $\dim X = \infty$...

Comment: O.K.!  ...Question which bothers me is, even in the case that $\operatorname{dim}X =\infty$, there is no problem in the argument of the proof of Theorem 14.114?~(I'll also check it out). We should adopt the convention that equidimensionality of $X$ means that $\operatorname{dim}X' = d <\infty $  for all $X'$?